# How to return each string in a separate TouchableOpacity with FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have got an array of string which I need to return in a FlatList.
But I am not sure of how I can implement this idea.
Can I do it in here?   {item.answers}
Or I should restructure my API in order to make it work the way I need it?
Here is my code:

```
const DATA = [
  {
    question:
      "In class, how oftern do you purposely encourage others around you?",
    answers: [
      "Bully: Use physical aggression to get my own way. Pick on others a lot",
      "Rude: Treats others without care. Mild put downs. Passive. Aggressive",
      "Doubting: Do not believe in others. Hard to see the good in others",
      "Encouraging: Support that instils courage and inner confidence in others",
      "People Pleasing: Saying nice things to others but for a selfish reason eg. to be liked more.",
      "Sarcastic: The nice things that you say are almost always fake or passive aggressive",
      "Manipulating: Try to get others to do what you want by telling them what they want to hear",
    ],
  },
];


const Item = ({ item, onPress, style }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.item, style]}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{item.answers}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

const QuizScreen = () => {
  // const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
   
    return (
      <Item
        item={item}
        onPress={() => {}}
        style={{ backgroundColor: Colors.primary }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Comment: what is your desire output?

Comment: all strings from Answers but all of them separate, at the moment I am getting all of them merget together in one box. What I need is all of them separately in different boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
const Item = ({ item, onPress, style }) => {
  return item.answers.map((value,i) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.item, style]}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{value}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
))}
```

This way you can render all answers separately